# Include library PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to include the Threema library in my Codeigniter project, but I have trouble doing it. [This is the library.](https://github.com/rugk/threema-msgapi-sdk-php)
I followed the instructions, created an autoload with composer, but I don't know how to make it work. I have an helper that looks like this :

```
require_once APPPATH . "libraries/Threema/vendor/autoload.php";

    //define your connection settings
    $settings = new ConnectionSettings(
    '*xxxxx',
    'xxxxxx'
    );

    $publicKeyStore = new Threema\MsgApi\PublicKeyStores\File("pathTo/threema_key.php");
    $connector = new Connection($settings, $publicKeyStore);
```

I have the error :

> Class 'ConnectionSettings' not found

I tried to do as the guide by using the keyword "use" but that doesn't work either :

```
use Threema\MsgApi\Connection;
use Threema\MsgApi\ConnectionSettings;
use Threema\MsgApi\Receiver;
```

What is the simple way to install this library in a CodeIgniter environment ?

Comment: Have you tried `new Threema\MsgApi\Connection()` instead of just `new Connection`? Same with `ConnectionSettings`

Answer (score 0):

try to change this line

```
require $SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ./'libraries/Threema/vendor/autoload.php';
```